# Check if element is dropped inside bounding box

Tags: javascript

```
elementIsDroppedInShowcase(event: CdkDragRelease): boolean {
  const showcaseDocument = document.getElementById('builder-showcase');
  const clientRectangle = showcaseDocument.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(clientRectangle.toJSON());
  console.log(event.source.getFreeDragPosition());

  // check if x,y coordinates of getFreeDragPosition is in clientRectangle

  return false;
}
```

The value for `clientRectangle` is (which is the boundingBox):

```
{
  "x": 350,
  "y": 182,
  "width": 900,
  "height": 398,
  "top": 182,
  "right": 1250,
  "bottom": 580,
  "left": 350
}
```

Comment: so you shuld have the screen as the box and just check if element is inside the bounding box witch is inside the screen

Comment: something like this screen 800x800 boundingBox 200x200 element 100X100 if bounding box at 100t100l element at 150t 150l...   elementTop > boundingBoxTop AND  (elementTop + elementHeight) < (boundingBoxTop + boundingBoxHeight) = true